# Парсинг текстового поля Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть текстовое поле, заполненное по следующему шаблону: [цифра0][произвольный набор символов1][цифра1][разделитель]...[произвольный набор символовN-1][цифраN-1][разделитель][произвольный набор символовN]

Цифра содержит кол-во символов в следующем за ней после разделителя текстовом поле (во всех случаях кроме начала строки, где текст идёт сразу после указания его длинны - без разделителя).

Пример строки: "12column_name79#col_value13#..." , где [12 = цифра0, длина идущего далее поля][column_name7 = произвольный набор символов1][9 = цифра2, длина идущего далее поля][# = разделитель][col_value = произвольный набор символов2][13 = цифра3, длина идущего далее поля][# = разделитель][... аналогичные конструкции энное кол-во раз].

Мне нужно произвести изрядные шаманства с этими данными, но первым делом, нужно как-то распарсить строку: вытащить из строки все [произвольный набор символов] и собрать их в массив/временную таблицу.
Полагаю, тут как-то могут помочь регулярные выражения, но даже не знаю, как подступиться.

p.s. важно, что [произвольный набор символов] вполне может содержать цифры, так что просто заранее начитать все цифры, и как-то итеративно двигать по substring'ам, суммируя длинны не выйдет.

Comment: произвольный набор символов у вас там задан фиксированной длиной строки, которая перед ним, так то не суть важно, какие там символы буквы или цифры. Странно, что между `12` и `column_name7` разделитель отсутствует, хотя далее везде `длина поля#поле`.

Comment: А есть образец реальных данных? А то может опечатка тут в начале с разделителем?

Comment: Несложным REPLACE превращаете своё значение в массив либо JSON массив. А дальше парсинг регуляркой по шаблону. Полностью согласен с предыдущим оратором - читаем [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) и выполняем пункты 5 и 3.